# Selenium hovering over an element

Tags: python, selenium, hover

How can I hover over an elment for a certain period of time,there are hidden items in a combobox submenu and it wont show onless I hover on the submenu for 1-5 seconds. Basically in python how can i set the amount of time to hover over an element?

So far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get('')
element_to_hover_over = firefox.find_element_by_id("")

hover = ActionChains(firefox).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
```

Comment: can you show the pages source code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [time.sleep](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep)

```
# Pause for 5 seconds
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

Although if you are using you're 1-5 seconds as a timeout condition, you could also you Selenium's `WebDriverWait` functionality (see [docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-waits)) to wait for whatever you wish to happen after 1-5 seconds.

Comment: It works but it is unstable, sometimes it hovers and other time it doesnt, any other ideas?

Comment: @user1582983 hmm, not sure. That must be a bug in the hover action. From my experience, Selenium can be rather quirky with actions like hovering. If there's a way you can avoid relying on this functionality exclusively, I'd recommend it.

Comment: Could you take a look at the website i am crawling? This is the website, https://mbsdisclosure.fanniemae.com/PoolTalk2/index.html, > Advanced Search > #then the combo box I am looking for the sub menu option for Preliminary Mega > Preliminary Mega: Fannie Mae/Ginnie Mae backed Adjustable Rate

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking for a creative way around it.  Typically, hover menus have visibility activated or deactivated by snippets of javascript, and the actual coding of the options are functionally there before they appear on the webpage. If you use selenium to scrape the combobox element for the hidden text, and then use selenium's built in select function that manipulates comboboxes, you can probably find a way to manipulate the combobox without having to resort to actual mouse manipulation (a buggy and not very reliable way to manipulate web pages).